# Access custom UIView class delegate method from parent class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, protocols, uitextfielddelegate

I have a class name `AccountRecoveryViewController`. Here in `UITableView`'s "customcell" which is called `AccountRecoveryExpandedCell` in `- (void)awakeFromNib` method I simply add a `customView` called `RIPasscodeView`. And set all necessary parameter.

Like this:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    RIPasscodeView *passcodeView = [[RIPasscodeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake (32, 144, 278, 35)];

    passcodeView.innerSpaceValue = 20;
    passcodeView.placeHolder = @"-";
    passcodeView.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:250.0f/255.0f green:110.0f/255.0f blue:40.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    passcodeView.delegate = self;
    [self addSubview:passcodeView];
}
```

In `RIPasscodeView` I set the `UITextFields` delegate methods (`textFieldShouldReturn` or `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`) and it's works fine.

But now I want to access those `UITextFields` delegate methods from my `AccountRecoveryViewController`. Because I have to change the position of my `tableview` (up a little bit) by tap gesture, but the `UITextFields` delegate methods which is not available in this `AccountRecoveryViewController` class.

How can I do that? If any one have any suggestion or query please knock me.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options to do this.

1. Create your own Protocol, and handle on action from inside the `RIPasscodeView` to `AccountRecoveryViewController`.
2. Assign the UITextField delegate to your parent controller, by passing the parent controller reference.
3. Use `KVO`.
4. Use `NSNotificationCentre` to notify your parent controller.

Cheers.